# clover is using java version as 1.4 for some modules

Tags: java, code-coverage, javac, clover

clover is using java version as 1.4 for some modules and 1.8 for others. We have tried setting the version in `clover-setup` property (`source="1.8"`), in `build.xml` and other workarounds too but no luck. Although if I am putting the source as 1.8 in javac target, it is working fine but that would not be a correct approach.

```
[clover] Processing files at 1.8 source level.
[clover] Processing files at 1.4 source level.
```